# simple sum of Unicode symbol codes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, windows, unicode-string

I want to do this:

1) Click event of **Convert !** button

> User must type 2 value into writable edit controls. After pressing **Convert !** program must set sum of these characters Unicode values to first read-only edit control (it's near of " **=** " symbol). For example, if I set first edit control value as `є` (which its UTF-16 (hex) encoding value is **`0x0404 (0404)`**. It's also known as *Cyrillic Capital Letter Ukrainian IE*) and second edit control value as `@` (which its UTF-16 (hex) encoding value is **`0x0040 (0040)`**. It's also known as Commercial At), then result must be a symbol: `ф` (its UTF-16 encoding value is **`0x0444 (0444)`**). Therefore, its value equals to sum of other edit controls UTF-16 encoding values. How can I do this?

2) Click event of **Undo** button

> By clicking **Undo** button, it must sets the value of edit control the below this button. This value should be `є` symbol (as you see its Unicode encoding value is extraction of `sum` and `second edit control's` *value*. How can I do this?

I've searched out for these problem for 2 weeks in Google, MSDN and some different forums. But I couldn't find any helpful topic. I could find only the `MultiByteCharacterSet`, `_mbclen`, `mblen` and `_mblen_l` functions. If these functions are useful for me, how can I use it/them in my program? Please, give me advice. I'm new to VC++.

## Edit

> User must enter a character. It is maybe a digit or letter. Not a word or sequence of characters or number.

Thanks for any attention.

P.S: If there are too many and *poor* mistakes in my grammar, and if the question is duplicate so sorry...

Best regards,
Mirjalal.

[image]

Comment: Adding Unicode codepoint values is a very meaningless operation.  The result is a completely random glyph.  Just gibberish.  Including nothing at all when the font you use doesn't have the glyph, the result matches a surrogate or it overflows.  Don't write programs that produce gibberish.

Comment: @HansPassant I know. But can I do this ?

Comment: You can do anything you want, just don't expect help with a meaningless quest.  Use a random number generator, it will be easier to implement.

Comment: Random number generator for this problem ? But how? Please, explain. I couldn't understand.

Comment: Are there any parts of this task that you do know how to do? Can you read the edit controls? Can you add two characters? Can you write to the readonly edit control? These all seem to be very elementary steps. So what's the problem?

Comment: [operator+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Arithmetic_operators) will do, if you know what you're doing. [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is assumed to have been read.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP yes. For example, I can get, set input value, convert this value and also item ID, working with member variables and so on.  My main problem is that I couldn't convert input value to its Unicode-16 (hex) value. Pquestionquestionp.P.S please read question again. I added something.

Comment: Good news: You don't have to convert it to its (hex) value! The question, however, implies an abundant lack of understanding, how computers store values. Do you not have a book that explains these things? At any rate, simply cast your `wchar_t` values to `unsigned int`, add them, and cast back to `wchar_t`. As Hans pointed out earlier, the result is generally meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input value is already equal to its unicode-16 value. No conversion is needed.

```css
CString in1(L'1');
CString in2(L'2');
CString sum(wchar_t(in1[0] + in2[0]));
```

Comment: nice :)
 it's working *sometimes* for me.
here *sometimes* mean, when the first inputs value is `A` and second ones is `B` the result is actually nothing. but it working for some other symbols. And I also want to know it's not working for all symbols?

 I couldn't understand that what's the `[0]` ? I changed these indices to another digit it not worked.

Thanks.

Comment: in1[0] is the first character in the in1 string. in1[1] would be the second character in the string (if there was a second character). The arithmetic does "work" for all symbols, but not all results produce a displayable character.